# graphite vs collectd. retentions not applied

Tags: graphite, whisper, graphite-carbon

I have installed collectd on BIND9 hosts and configured it to pass metrics to graphite. I want to be able to view metrics for at least 1 month but retentions in storage-schema.conf not applied for collectd section, and applied last default section that stores only last 24h metrics.
I understand that I need to set correct retentions regex to match metrics but it is seems to me that is correct already but it does not work :(

My **storage-schemas.conf** looks like this for now:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[mxservers]
pattern = ^mx-servers\.*
retentions = 60s:7d,5m:2y 

[ns.servers]
pattern = ^ns\d\.collectd\..*
retentions = 60s:7d,10m:2y

[collectd]
pattern =^collectd\.*
retentions = 60s:7d,10m:2y 

# *** Netapp Monitoring ***
[netapp.capacity]
pattern = ^netapp\.capacity\.*
retentions = 15m:100d, 1d:5y

[netapp.poller.capacity]
pattern = ^netapp\.poller\.capacity\.*
retentions = 15m:100d, 1d:5y

[netapp.perf]
pattern = ^netapp\.perf\.*
retentions = 60s:35d, 5m:100d, 15m:395d, 1h:5y

[netapp.poller.perf]
pattern = ^netapp\.poller\.perf\.*
retentions = 60s:35d, 5m:100d, 15m:395d, 1h:5y

[netapp.perf7]
pattern = ^netapp\.perf7\.*
retentions = 60s:35d, 5m:100d, 15m:395d, 1h:5y

[netapp.poller.perf7]
pattern = ^netapp\.poller\.perf7\.*
retentions = 60s:35d, 5m:100d, 15m:395d, 1h:5y
# *** Netapp Monitoring ***

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

I have a problem with section named - [ns.servers],
tried to set regex in it to:

```
^ns\d\.collectd\.
^ns\d\.collectd\..*
^ns.\.collectd\.
^ns.\.collectd\..*
```

None of them solves the problem.
The metrics are stored with names like this:

```
ns1.collectd.load.load.shortterm
ns2.collectd.load.load.longterm
ns1.collectd.interface-bond0.if_packets.rx
ns2.collectd.interface-bond0.if_packets.tx
```

Please help me to set correct regex to get it match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized what the problem is! I take a look to `/var/log/carbon/creates.log` and found that my metrics for collecd is stored as `ns2/collectd.*` - "hostname"+"/"+"collectd" - because in configuration of collectd on DNS-servers there was an option `Postfix "/collectd"` that make this.

```
05/06/2017 09:54:22 :: creating database file /var/lib/graphite/whisper/ns2/collectd/cpu-1/cpu-idle.wsp (archive=[(60, 1440)] xff=None agg=None)
05/06/2017 09:54:22 :: new metric ns2/collectd.disk-sda.disk_octets.write matched schema default_1min_for_1day
05/06/2017 09:54:22 :: new metric ns2/collectd.disk-sda.disk_octets.write matched aggregation schema default
```

So the solution was to make regex look like this: `pattern = ^ns[1-2]\/collectd\.*` - escaped "/" - character
and then I deleted old metrics and new metric files was created with correct retentions!

```
05/06/2017 11:32:12 :: creating database file /var/lib/graphite/whisper/ns2/collectd/df-boot-efi/df_complex-free.wsp (archive=[(60, 10080), (600, 105120)] xff=None agg=None)
05/06/2017 11:32:12 :: new metric ns2/collectd.interface-eth0.if_errors.tx matched schema ns.servers
05/06/2017 11:32:12 :: new metric ns2/collectd.interface-eth0.if_errors.tx matched aggregation schema default
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to configure the regexes in storage-schemas.conf after the .wsp files were created? If so you have to resize the existing .wsp files manually. You can do this with the whisper-resize utility included in the whisper package (or just delete the files and let carbon recreate them).

storage-schemas.conf is only applied when creating a new .wsp file.

Comment: Yes you are right, retention settings was changed after data files are created, so now I deleted old files and have to wait 1d+1minute to be sure that now all works as it should. Thank you.

Comment: you can verify the whisper files with the `whisper-info` utility. It will show you the retentions of the files.

Comment: I do not understand that output at all:
    whisper-info ns1/collectd/interface-bond0/if_packets/tx.wsp 
    maxRetention: 86400
    xFilesFactor: 0.5
    aggregationMethod: average
    fileSize: 17308

Archive 0
retention: 86400
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 1440
size: 17280
offset: 28

Comment: `whisper-info` shows metadata information about the whisper file. First part is the generic info, then comes the per archive info. In your case it should show something like:
> fileSize: 1382440
> maxRetention: 63072000
> aggregationMethod: average
> xFilesFactor: 0.5
> Archive 0
> retention: 604800
> size: 120960
> offset: 40
> points: 10080
> secondsPerPoint: 60
> Archive 1
> retention: 63072000
> size: 1261440
> offset: 121000
> points: 105120
> secondsPerPoint: 600

Comment: So I tested this and get some negative results. First thing: if I use whisper-resize it does what I need and files change their retentions, and I see **"Archive 0"** and **"Archive 1"** , but if I stop carbon-cache and remove that metrics from top level host directory (ns1, ns2) after carbon start newly created files still have same retentions ** as before **